# Burp not intercepting live video stream

Tags: burp-suite, http-proxy

I have set up Burp proxy to intercept requests of an Android app. I am able to intercept app API calls except for live video streams. I am not aware of how the video stream is implemented but assuming there should be WebSocket or HTTP requests made to stream video.

Please help me how can I intercept live streaming. My aim is to stream video on a laptop.

Comment: The video is likely streamed via Websocket. Burp treats these differently than regular HTTP requests.

Comment: also burp didn't handle data streams very well even over http, not sure it's changed now.

Comment: How do you know it's not over a completely different protocol?

Comment: @multithr3at3d not at all sure. How can I find that?

Comment: @ShashwatKumar by using tcpdump from the device itself or from a device that sees all of its traffic